# MPI local variables gets corrupted, why?

Tags: c, mpi

Disclosure: This is a homework problem.  I'm currently writing a matrix multiplier in MPI, and I'm trying to diagnose a segfault.  I've narrowed it down to a given segment of the code, and I'm completely baffled as to why this is happening, or else I have a fundamental misunderstanding of MPI (entirely possible).

The master process has ID 0, and the 4 slave processes have ID 1-4.  After the slave processes have calculated their chunks of the output matrix, and they send them back to the master, I receive them with this code.  I've included some print statements that show where this variable corruption takes place:

```
    for(i=1;i<numtasks;i++) {
        source = i;
        thischunksize = lindex-findex+1;
        rc = MPI_Irecv(&Rbuf, thischunksize*rnx, MPI_INT, source, RCHUNKTAG, MP\
I_COMM_WORLD, request+4);
        printf("0: D Just checking, i is %d and source is %d\n", i, source);
        rc = MPI_Wait(request+4, status+4);
        printf("0: E Just checking, i is %d and source is %d\n", i, source);
        for(j=0;j<thischunksize*rnx;j++)                                
          {                                                                                                                                        
            R[findex*rnx + j] = Rbuf[j];                                
          }
}
```

And the output is:

```
0: D Just checking, i is 1 and source is 1
0: E Just checking, i is 0 and source is 0
```

So these variables change in value while the MPI_Wait function is running.  Why?  The i variable IS used by both the master and slave processes, but I didn't think this would matter; I assumed each process had its own memory; isn't that the whole point of MPI?

I can show the rest of the code if needed, but I'm not sure that it's necessary.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for future reference.

Instead of

```
rc = MPI_Irecv(&Rbuf, thischunksize*rnx, MPI_INT, source, RCHUNKTAG, MP\
I_COMM_WORLD, request+4);
```

It should have been

```
rc = MPI_Irecv(Rbuf, thischunksize*rnx, MPI_INT, source, RCHUNKTAG, MP\
I_COMM_WORLD, request+4);
```

I was taking the address of a pointer foolishly.  I'm not sure if I should even keep this...If I should just delete the question, let me know, I will.